# How to make windows recognize to "pt_br.utf-8" in R

Tags: r, windows, encoding, shiny

I am using windows 10 and Rstudio and I didn´t find a way to overcome the following problem. What I already tried:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
```

or

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "pt_br.utf-8")
```

This problem does not appear using MacOs of Linux.

The error message is this:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5736
Warning in Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "pt_br.utf-8") :
OS reports request to set locale to "pt_br.utf-8" cannot be honored
```

[image]

The image above is how the Shiny application runs on this windows machine.

Comment: On my system I get a Brazilian Portuguese locale with `Sys.setlocale(locale = "Portuguese")`, which I find surprising.

Comment: Hey Roland, thanks for you message, I tried this approach and still the problem persists. This might be something related to Shiny configurations.

Answer (score 1):

This is intrinsic to your OS. You must first of all find which locale are locally installed. You may find this other [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/166089/where-is-the-list-of-available-windows-locales) useful on this point.

The point is: when perusing the list of installed language locale, you must identify the ones which are compatible with Portuguese characters, such as:

```
locale -a
>pt_BR
>pt_BR.ISO8859-1
>pt_BR.UTF-8
>pt_PT
>pt_PT.ISO8859-1
>pt_PT.ISO8859-15
>pt_PT.UTF-8
```

[Retrieved from my Mac OSX Terminal window; selected instances]

*Then* you may set one of these locales to your R interface.